# Javascript uncaught exception handling / window.onerror msg argument format

Tags: javascript, error-handling, chromium

I need to be able to catch one type of error which can happen in lot of different pages/scripts and execute custom logic when this error happens. I planned to use

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
    if ({{my specific error happened}}){
        {{do some custom work}};
        return true;
    }
    //do nothing and let the browser notify the user of all the other errors
}
```

so somewhere I can do `throw {{my specific error}}` and catch it in `window.onerror`. I tried `throw "Magic";` but then in `window.onerror` I get `msg == "Uncaught Magic"`. Will this **"Uncaught "** part of `msg` always precede my thrown string? Can I rely on it to detect my specific error?
Or is there some other mechanism to detect error type in `window.onerror`?
I only need it to work in Chromium.

Comment: I realise I'm not helping at all... but "Uncaught Magic" is perhaps the funniest exception I've ever seen. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers now pass the actual error object. Not sure which browsers support this. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror) is said that Gecko 31 is required. No idea about chrome and others.

You can create a custom Error like:

```
Magic = function( message ) {
    this.name = 'Magic';
    this.message = message;
}
Magic.prototype = new Error();
Magic.prototype.constructor = Magic;
```

throw it somewhere:

```
throw new Magic('Kaboom');
```

and catch it in `window.onerror` like this:

```
window.onerror = function ( message, filename, lineno, colno, error ){
    if ( error !== undefined && error.hasOwnProperty( "name" ) && error.name == "Magic"){
        alert("some uncaught magic caused: "  + message +" - in "+filename +"("+lineno+")" );
        return true;
    }
}
```

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqb0gd10/2/)**

---

you could also check if message contains "Magic", but then you might accidently catch other errors containing "Magic".

---

ps: sorry for necro, I stumbled over this searching for the same.. so I thought I might as well add an answer..